Sampled curve only consider one spline (workaround)
I created a grid with an underlying curve and the "poles" are splines instanced on the curve points, poining up, the base curve gets duplicated n times and they are placed along the instanced splines forming "rails". It all works well, but the problem I face is that: when I split the underlying curve into two splines, the rails don't follow along the two underlying splines, they get like portrayed in the image2. They get sort of revoled along the poles back and forth a few times. Is there a workaround so the splitting gets reflected in the rails as expected?




Any brainstrom would be appreciated guys!


Fixed! It was only a question of capturing the index from the original curve.
